# Insert data array within array in database in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array followers_array and inside that I have array followers. Now I want to insert all the data in database. I have tried this but this insert only three data and not all
I want to insert data of an array which contain another array.

```
example 
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1766191289
        [username] => club_prichesok
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13652273_1748726562036923_750729706_a.jpg
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1825482289
        [username] => recepturo
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/13269510_1062313797193421_2145524856_a.jpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1558269170
        [username] => bossbabesbrand
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13652188_776051655868683_440592047_a.jpg
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3150718948
        [username] => aiyubpixster1
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14597497_1333447786679600_2495297650182586368_a.jpg
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3126365193
        [username] => aiyubmunshi22
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12960010_1525961487711830_121043771_a.jpg
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 786675309
        [username] => a_trvn
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14478472_200908700343641_544747813301387264_a.jpg
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3920937922
        [username] => campins09
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14515676_1750967491822509_1220506517271216128_a.jpg
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3101694007
        [username] => apriyapari
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12907442_1754066311508992_471114618_a.jpg
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3522063531
        [username] => soccergirrl.x
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14566773_1820095541541963_7245353788171616256_n.jpg
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4307621933
        [username] => carmii_licious
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/15624190_382611378742665_5984516355464888320_a.jpg
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4120637171
        [username] => _cek.newphoto.or.unfollow_
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/15306790_705623506273370_4297264141430685696_a.jpg
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3019429401
        [username] => gungaoto
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14624240_214178872360167_5880385332934868992_a.jpg
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4157340771
        [username] => hairstyle_makeup_style
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/15306541_1806174429600270_600008151021912064_a.jpg
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3514079761
        [username] => jemxma_esrn
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14606945_318707198522914_4406240531315687424_a.jpg
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4374792130
        [username] => liindsay20
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/15876231_1774071109522171_5041779443538853888_a.jpg
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3669715747
        [username] => subhanallahh__
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/15534754_192323887898801_4040343084729368576_a.jpg
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3111272383
        [username] => irshad.pixster
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1114256851
        [username] => pixsterstudio
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11335149_984470211587963_1696181727_a.jpg
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4374336687
        [username] => putrysyafinazsyuhizam
        [profie_pic_url] => http://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/15875998_185924578548483_3898112154640842752_n.jpg
    )
```

now my table in database contain three fields id username and profile_pic_url
I want to insert these data in database.I tried but it saves only three data where as I have 25 data in array.

whole code
Here is my full code. please tell me where am I going wrong.

```
  <?php
  error_reporting(0);
  require('./vendor/autoload.php');
   $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Cannot connect to  the DB');
     mysql_select_db('insta',$con);
  $username = $_GET['user'];
  $pass = $_GET['pass'];

  if(!empty($pass) && !empty($username))
   {
   $i = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram(false);

  $i->setUser($username, $pass);

   if($i->settings->islogged() == false)
  {

    echo "You are not logged in.";
   }
  else
   {

    $a = $i->getUsernameId($username);

    $helper = null;
    $followers = [];

    $followers_array = array();

    do {
        if (is_null($helper)) {
            $helper = $i->getSelfUserFollowers();
        } else {
            $helper = $i->getSelfUserFollowers($helper->getNextMaxId());
        }

        $followers = array_merge($followers, $helper->getUsers());
    } while (!is_null($helper->getNextMaxId()));

    foreach ($followers as $follower) {
        $username = $follower->getUsername();
        $profie_pic_url = $follower->getProfilePicUrl();
        $id = $follower->getPk();
        $status = $i->userFriendship($id);

         $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `followers`  (username,profile_pic_url,follower_id)
          VALUES ('".$username."','".$profie_pic_url."','".$id."')");


       // if ($status->getFollowing() == false)
      //  {
         array_push($followers_array,array('id' => $id,'username' =>  $username,'profie_pic_url' => $profie_pic_url));
      //  }
    }
       if($query){
      echo "Data inserted </br>";
      }




   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($followers_array);



  }
 }
else
 {
     echo"username is required";
  }

 ?>
```

here is my table with three data.
[image]

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: thank you Riggs for your valuable sugesstion. I will keep in mind

Comment: And once you've learnt those libraries, read about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) so that you aren't vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: There are too many method calls to classes you must have written. There is no way we can tell from this amount of information what may have gone wrong with your data, since there cannot be any obvious syntax errors. You need to track the state of your arrays through the entire code, printing their contents out at each iteration and compare them to the expected data.

Comment: so shall i post my whole code here?? if you want I can post it here.

Comment: It's possible that some character in the data you're trying to insert causes the problem. Try to escape al especial characters with something like: mysqli_real_escape_string or mysql_real_escape_string (deprecated)

Comment: still getting three values. where as i am getting all 25 value when I use print_r

Comment: Only 3 inserts in the database and all 25 in `$followers_array`? I would try to insert the 4th manually with Phpmyadmin to see if the sql works (if you didn't do ti yet) It's what I do to check whenever I have problems with queries.

Comment: ok i will try your trick yes.. when I use print_r($followers_array) i get 25 data and when I insert using above script I get on three data.

Comment: yes I am able to insert using phpmyadmin @MarioZ